# convert a java.net.InetAddress to a long

Tags: java, byte, unsigned, signed

I would like to convert a `java.net.InetAddress` and I fight with the signed / unsigned problems. Such a pain.

I read [convert from short to byte and viceversa in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114935/convert-from-short-to-byte-and-viceversa-in-java) and [Why byte b = (byte) 0xFF is equals to integer -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677957/why-byte-b-byte-0xff-is-equals-to-integer-1)

And as a result came up with:

```
     final byte [] pumpeIPAddressRaw =
        java.net.InetAddress.getByName (pumpeIPAddressName).getAddress ();

     final long pumpeIPAddress =
         ((pumpeIPAddressRaw [0] & 0xFF) << (3*8)) +
         ((pumpeIPAddressRaw [1] & 0xFF) << (2*8)) +
         ((pumpeIPAddressRaw [2] & 0xFF) << (1*8)) +
         (pumpeIPAddressRaw [3] &  0xFF);

     android.util.Log.i (
        Application.TAG, "LOG00120: Setzte Pumpen Addresse : " +
        pumpeIPAddress + ":" + pumpeIPPort);
```

And guess what the log still shows:

```
04-10 13:12:07.398 I/ch.XXXX.remote.Application(24452): LOG00120: Setzte Pumpen Addresse : -1063035647:27015
```

Does anybody know what I am still doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`& 0xff` blocks sign extension during conversion from `byte` to `int`, but your expression also contains conversion from `int` to `long` and you need to block sign extension during this conversion as well:

```
final long pumpeIPAddress =
      (((pumpeIPAddressRaw [0] & 0xFF) << (3*8)) + 
      ((pumpeIPAddressRaw [1] & 0xFF) << (2*8)) +
      ((pumpeIPAddressRaw [2] & 0xFF) << (1*8)) +
      (pumpeIPAddressRaw [3] &  0xFF)) & 0xffffffffl;
```

Alternatively, you can convert from `byte` to `long` in a single step, by marking the second operand of `& 0xff` operation as `long` using `l` suffix:

```
final long pumpeIPAddress =
      ((pumpeIPAddressRaw [0] & 0xFFl) << (3*8)) + 
      ((pumpeIPAddressRaw [1] & 0xFFl) << (2*8)) +
      ((pumpeIPAddressRaw [2] & 0xFFl) << (1*8)) +
      (pumpeIPAddressRaw [3] &  0xFFl);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that the answer by [user2660727 is good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22070468/198397), because it uses only standard Java, is short and efficient. Correcting a few issues (negative values, buffer length), my suggested solution is:

```
InetAddress bar = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
buffer.put(new byte[] { 0,0,0,0 });
buffer.put(bar.getAddress());
buffer.position(0);
long address = buffer.getLong();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String ip = "127.0.0.1";
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ip);

// ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN by default
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.SIZE);
buffer.put(inetAddress.getAddress());
buffer.position(0);
Long longValue = buffer.getLong();
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! to make this a better question, can you give more explanation about how this addresses the question, rather than just post the code? thanks!