# Java - Print random IP addresses in a given range

Tags: java, ip, range

I am trying to get a random ip address from given range.

EX: startIp = "192.168.1.0" ; endIp = "192.168.2.255"

I tried of converting range to cidr and getting randomIp for cidr list using SubnetUtils but no luck.

Is there any effective way of generating a random ip from given ip-range or an api which can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve by following the steps:

1. Convert the two [IPs to numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836155/convert-ip-between-ipv4-and-numerical-format-in-java)

> ```
> InetAddress i= InetAddress.getByName(IPString);
> int intRepresentation= ByteBuffer.wrap(i.getAddress()).getInt();
> ```

2. Generate [random between the limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271598/java-generate-random-number-between-two-given-values)

> ```
> r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
> ```

3. Convert result back [numeric to IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836155/convert-ip-between-ipv4-and-numerical-format-in-java)

> ```
> i= InetAddress.getByName(String.valueOf(intRepresentation));
> String ip= i.getHostAddress();
> ```

Comment: this approach working fine till max of 128.255.255.255. For remaining its returning negative values and resulting below excpetion:

`Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: -847933385
 at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
 at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source) .....`

Comment: @Forece85 convert to long instead see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087800/convert-a-java-net-inetaddress-to-a-long