# Byte type is weird

Tags: java, android

I need to send some bytes over UDP Protocol the start squence is 0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF

When I define like this:

```
byte [] begin = {0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF};
```

I get an error saying I need to cast those to byte type. Far as I know 0xFF doesn't exced the byte type so what is the problem ?

If i write this it works :

```
byte [] begin = {(byte) 0xFF,(byte) 0xFF,(byte) 0xFF,(byte) 0xFF,(byte) 0xFF,(byte) 0xFF};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677957/why-byte-b-byte-0xff-is-equals-to-integer-1 take a look

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Far as I know 0xFF doesn't exced the byte type so what is the problem ?

Actually it does. Bytes are signed in Java, so the range is -0x80 to 0x7f (inclusive).

(The fact that the `byte` type *is* signed is a pain in the neck, but there we go...)

Comment: If i cast it works ? Or do I need to define to another data type

Comment: @opc0de: Yes, casting is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1):

Any literal number in java is compiled as an int. Even if it's declared in a situation like here, where a byte is the expected value. The cast is the thing which actually transforms that literal int into a byte.

Comment: Except that there's an implicit conversion from a constant `int` expression within the range of `byte` to `byte` itself. The problem is that `0xff` isn't within the range of `byte`. Try it with (say) `0x7f` and you don't need the cast.